# SSIS package for Insert and Update

Tags: sql, ssis

Pretty new to SSIS packages. Need a solution for the following data flow scenarios.

Have two identical tables on both source and destination databases.

**Source Table**

```
ID     | Employee   
------ | ------
1      | Paul          
2      | Jane
3      | John
```

**Scenario 1**

Destination Table before insert

```
ID     | Employee   
------ | ------
1      | Paul          
3      | John
```

Destination Table after insert

```
ID     | Employee   
------ | ------
1      | Paul          
2      | Jane
3      | John
```

**Scenario 2**

Destination Table before update

```
ID     | Employee   
------ | ------
1      | Paul          
2      | Kate
3      | John
```

Destination Table after insert

```
ID     | Employee   
------ | ------
1      | Paul          
2      | Jane
3      | John
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

The ask that you are asking is an upsert scenario. You can follow this [link](http://radacad.com/insert-update-and-delete-destination-table-with-ssis) for one of such implementation.

1. Inserted in order  - This is not possible. You can't re-order the data while performing data loads. If you still deem it necessary, then the option you need to chose is to truncate the data and do the load again.
2. Data to be updated on match

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest you use a linked server if possible. SSIS does not really provide a way to do merges (aka upserts) built-in anyways. If you use a linked server you would be able to do the merge right in a query. If you use SSIS, the easiest way is to just upload your data from the source to a new table on the destination, then run the [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) command in a query (Execute SQL task).